# RFC3447 OBJECT IDENTIFIER semantic

Tags: rsa

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-B.1

```
id-sha256    OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {
      joint-iso-itu-t(2) country(16) us(840) organization(1)
      gov(101) csor(3) nistalgorithm(4) hashalgs(2) 1
  }
```

How to read this definition? In another word, how to convert this into a bit stream? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929050/how-does-asn-1-encode-an-object-identifier -- which was my first google hit for encode ASN.1 OBJECT IDENTIFIER.

Comment: Yes, but we can top that answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the notes of paragraph 9.2 of that document, it lists all the encodings in hexadecimal values. It does so for PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for signature generation, but it certainly contains the OID's internally - `06 LL { OID }` where LL species the length of the BER encoded OID:

> For the six hash functions mentioned in Appendix B.1, the DER
> encoding T of the DigestInfo value is equal to the following:

```
  MD2:     (0x) 30 20  30 0c  06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 02  05 00  04 10 || H.
  MD5:     (0x) 30 20  30 0c  06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 05  05 00  04 10 || H.
  SHA-1:   (0x) 30 21  30 09  06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00  04 14 || H.
  SHA-256: (0x) 30 31  30 0d  06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01  05 00 04  20 || H.
  SHA-384: (0x) 30 41  30 0d  06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 02  05 00 04  30 || H.
  SHA-512: (0x) 30 51  30 0d  06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 03  05 00 04  40 || H.
```

I'll add SHA-224:

```
  SHA-224: (0x) 30 2D 30 0D 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 04 05 00 04 1C || H.
```

where `||` is concatenation and `H` is the hash value.

---

The ASN.1 syntax is officially defined in

> ISO/IEC 8824: Information technology - Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1): Information object specification

and the BER/DER method of encoding that is applied is specified in

> ISO/IEC 8825-1:  Information technology - ASN.1 encoding rules: Specification of Basic Encoding Rules (BER), Canonical Encoding Rules (CER) and Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER)

And the OID encoding is in paragraph 8.19 for the 2010 version of that document (an errata exists). How to actually encode it is explained in [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24720842/589259)

Comment: FWIW PKCS1v2.2 = RFC8017 Nov. 2016, after the date of the Q and your original A, has (correct) SHA-224 plus SHA-512/224 SHA-512/256 (with some typos, see the errata). But no SHA3 alas.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Of course, but nobody uses SHA-512/x at the moment. There was a time where it was faster, but now processors have SHA-256 support. If you want to have something modern you'd use PSS anyway, and for SHA-3 you would probably want to use SHAKE-256 instead of the normal MGF1...