# initial value for RSA and SHA-256 signature encoding

Tags: rsa, signature, sha-256

As described in RFC 8017, RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5 uses the following bytes during the encoding process :

0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60,  0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20

Does anybody know how to compute these values?

Comment: What do you mean by compute?

Comment: I mean : where do these values come from ?

Comment: Yes, I have already read this part of the RFC but can somebody explain it to me ?

Comment: Effectively the reverse of, but also answered by, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19542/rfc3447-object-identifier-semantic/ (3447 was the prior version of 8017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging the [RFC 8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2)

> 9.2.  EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5
>
> For the nine hash functions mentioned in Appendix B.1, the DER encoding T of the DigestInfo value is equal to the following:

and

> A.2.4.  RSASSA-PKCS-v1_5
>
> The object identifier for RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 SHALL be one of the
> following.

Both combined below;

```
Hash algorithm   OID                           the DER encoding T of the DigestInfo
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MD2              md2WithRSAEncryption          (0x)30 20 30 0c 06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 02 05 00 04 10 || H.
MD5              md5WithRSAEncryption          (0x)30 20 30 0c 06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 05 05 00 04 10 || H.
SHA-1            sha1WithRSAEncryption         (0x)30 21 30 09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00 04 14 || H.
SHA-224          sha224WithRSAEncryption       (0x)30 2d 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 04 05 00 04 1c || H.
SHA-256          sha256WithRSAEncryption       (0x)30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00 04 20 || H.
SHA-384          sha384WithRSAEncryption       (0x)30 41 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 02 05 00 04 30 || H.
SHA-512          sha512WithRSAEncryption       (0x)30 51 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 03 05 00 04 40 || H.
SHA-512/224      sha512-224WithRSAEncryption   (0x)30 2d 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 05 05 00 04 1c || H.
SHA-512/256      sha512-256WithRSAEncryption   (0x)30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 06 05 00 04 20 || H.
```

and in

> B.1.  Hash Functions
>
> The object identifiers id-md2, id-md5, id-sha1, id-sha224, id-sha256,
> id-sha384, id-sha512, id-sha512/224, and id-sha512/256 identify the
> respective hash functions:
>
> ```
>    id-md2      OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {
>        iso (1) member-body (2) us (840) rsadsi (113549)
>        digestAlgorithm (2) 2
>    }
>
>    id-md5      OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {
>        iso (1) member-body (2) us (840) rsadsi (113549)
>        digestAlgorithm (2) 5
>    }
>    ...
> ```

Therefore it is the DER encoding of the above object identifiers. See example on [A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER (5.9)](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html)

Comment: thank you for your help !